# How to model a probability distribution for this problem

Tags: probability

A reputed publisher claims that in the handbooks published by them misprints occur at the rate of $0.0024$
per page. What is the probability that in a randomly chosen handbook of $300$ pages, the third misprint will occur after examining $100$ pages?

What I thought is it should be $1 - \binom{100}{1 (0.0024) (0.9976)^{99}}$
Is my method the right way to approach such problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ and $Y$ be the number of misprints in the first 100 pages and the last 200 pages, respectively.
We are interested in
$$
p=\mathbb{P}(X=2)\mathbb{P}(Y\neq0).
$$

If we **disallow multiple misprints per page**, then $X\sim\operatorname{Binomial}(100,0.0024)$ and $Y\sim\operatorname{Binomial}(200,0.0024)$.
In this case,
$$
p=\left[\binom{100}{2}0.0024^{2}\left(1-0.0024\right)^{98}\right]\left[1-\left(1-0.0024\right)^{200}\right]\approx0.0085968\ldots
$$

If we **allow multiple misprints per page**, then $X\sim\operatorname{Poisson}(100\times0.0024)$ and $Y\sim\operatorname{Poisson}(200\times0.0024)$.
In this case,
$$
\frac{\left(100\times0.0024\right)^{2}e^{-100\times0.0024}}{2}\left(1-e^{-200\times0.0024}\right)\approx0.0086364\ldots
$$

Comment: What I did is.. since the third misprint is going to occur after 100 pages.. I took the complement of this statement and subtracted from 1. As you can see in the question itself. So is my way of looking at it right?

Comment: @Unknown: I don't think I understand your interpretation. The third misprint is not guaranteed to occur, and you haven't accounted for the first two misprints.

Comment: Yeah!! I misunderstood something... You solution is very transparent! Thanks buddy :)